# Trouble Turning a For Loop Into a While Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I'm supposed to turn the following function into a while loop. The function is supposed to count all the e's that appear in a certain string. Here's the function using a for loop:

```
function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let index = 0; index < word.length; index++) {
    let char = word[index];
    if (char === "e" || char === "E") {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
};
```

Here's my code:

```
function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0
  let index = 0;
  let char = word[index];
  
while (char === "e" || char === "E") {
index+= count;
}
return count;
}
};

console.log(eCounter("apple")); // => 1
console.log(eCounter("appleapple")); // => 2
console.log(eCounter("Appleee")); // => 3
```

If count and index are both 0, and char is defined, I'm not sure what to do next. When I console.log the strings, all three return zero.

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

I tried putting all of the code from the for loop into a while loop. I figured if I rearranged the   for loop code into a while loop, it would return the number of e's in each string. But when I run the code, all three counts return 0.

Comment: @vc74 the `wile` should check `index` against the length, not `count`.

Comment: [a generic pseudo code example](https://pastebin.com/SybgBQYW) - it's really straight forward to go from one to the other - then tweak the result if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to for loop

```js
function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0
  let index = 0;
  while (index < word.length) {
    const char = word[index]
    if (char === "e" || char === "E") {
      count++
    }
    index++
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop by the char index and increment it with `++` during reading the current character:

```js
function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0, index = 0;
  while (index < word.length) {
    const char = word[index++];
    (char === "e" || char === "E") && count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(eCounter('Evergrande'));
```

Some more fancy variant:

```js
function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0, index = 0, char;
  while (char = word[index++]) (char === "e" || char === "E") && count++;
  return count;
}

console.log(eCounter('Evergrande'));
```

Can be even an one-liner:

```js
const eCounter = (word, index = 0, count = 0, char = null) => { while (char = word[index++]) (char === "e" || char === "E") && count++; return count};

console.log(eCounter('Evergrande'));
```

Btw you can almost always replace a loop with `Array::reduce`:

```js
const eCounter = word => [...word].reduce((r, char) => char === "e" || char === "E" ? r + 1 : r, 0);

console.log(eCounter('Evergrande'));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   function eCounter(word) {
  let count = 0
  let index = 0;
  let char = word.split('');
  
while (char[index]) {

if(char[index] === 'e' || char[index] === 'E'){
  count = count + 1;
}

index++;
}
return count;
}
};
```

Comment: Hi @Lahiru, Welcome to SO, Thank you for your contribution, anything you answer here will be seen by many in future, so it is always better to include the little explanation like why and how your answer solves the asked question.